# How to create my own button for the Eclipse tool-bar?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gdb, gdbserver

I am assuming this falls under plug-in development, but I am unsure.

Are all things in Eclipse(e.g. a button), plug-ins?

Is it possible to look at source code of a button (e.g. the resume/step/pause button)?

I am very interested in how these buttons interact with GDB and what hooks there are for remote debugging, I am assuming via the GDB remote serial protocol.

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Yes, everything is a plug-in. There is extensive, complex, support for launching and debugging. Start by reading the [Program debug and launch support](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm) section of the Eclipse help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a button via a plug-in.

Source code of existing GDB integration is available. It is part of [CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/). [This page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development) explains how to download source and start development.